# Accidentally removed resolvconf package. How to create again?

Tags: package-management

I'm trying to install resolvconf.

When I write `sudo apt install resolvconf` in terminal I get

```
E:'resolvconf' No installation candidates for package.
```

How to install resolvconf, because I can't connect to the internet.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? `resolvconf` is the 18.04 universe repo.

Comment: ı am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You probably just need to enable the universe repository. Preferences / Software and Updates / Ubuntu Software and tick the box

Comment: There is no internet connection on my computer so I add nameserver ,

Comment: That's an important fact to add to your question.